# Spark streaming max records per batch interval

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

[New to Spark]

We have an Spark Streaming application that reads from Kinesis and writes to Redshift.

**Configuration**:

Number of receivers = 5

Batch interval = 10 mins

spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate = 2000 (records per second)

According to this config, the max records that can be read in a single batch can be calculated using below formula:

```
Max records per batch = batch_interval * 60 (convert mins to seconds) * 5 (number of receivers) * 2000 (max records per second per receiver)

10 * 60 * 5 * 2000 = 6,000,000
```

But the actual number of records is more that the max number.

Batch I - 6,005,886 records

Batch II - 6,001,623 records

Batch III - 6,010,148 records

Please note that receivers are not even reading at the max rate, the records read per receiver are near 1900 per second.

Why would this be happening ?